# Itcl What is the read property?

Tags: properties, tcl, itcl

I want to control read access to an Itcl public variable.  I can do this for write access using something such as:

```
package require Itcl
itcl::class base_model_lib {
    public variable filename ""
}
itcl::configbody base_model_lib::filename {
    puts "in filename write"
    dict set d_model filename $filename
}
```

The configbody defines what happens when config is called: `$obj configure -filename foo.txt`.  But how do I control what happens during the read?  Imagine that I want to do more than just look up a value during the read.

I would like to stay using the standard Itcl pattern of using cget/configure to expose these to the user.

So that is my question.  However, let me describe what I really want to do and you tell me if I should do something completely different :)

I like python classes.  I like that I can create a variable and read/write to it from outside the instance.  Later, when I want to get fancy, I'll create methods (using `@property` and `@property.setter`) to customize the read/write without the user seeing an API change.  I'm trying to do the same thing here.

My sample code also suggests something else I want to do.  Actually, the filename is stored internally in a dictionary.  i don't want to expose that entire dictionary to the user, but I do want them to be able to change values inside that dict.  So, really 'filename' is just a stub.  I don't want a public variable called that.  I instead want to use cget and configure to read and write a "thing", which I may chose to make a simple public variable or may wish to define a procedure for looking it up.

PS:  I'm sure I could create a method which took either one or two arguments.  If one, its a read and two its a write.  I assumed that wasn't the way to go as *I don't think* you could use the cget/configure method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Itcl variables are mapped to Tcl variables in a namespace whose name is difficult to guess. This means that you can get a callback whenever you read a variable (it happens immediately before the variable is actually read) via Tcl's standard tracing mechanism; all you need to do is to [create the trace in the constructor](http://wiki.tcl.tk/15988). This requires the use of `itcl::scope` and is best done with `itcl::code $this` so that we can make the callback be a private method:

```
package require Itcl
itcl::class base_model_lib {
    public variable filename ""
    constructor {} {
        trace add variable [itcl::scope filename] read [itcl::code $this readcallback]
    }
    private method readcallback {args} {         # You can ignore the arguments here
        puts "about to read the -filename"
        set filename "abc.[expr rand()]"
    }
}
```

All `itcl::configbody` does is effectively the equivalent for variable write traces, which are a bit more common, though we'd usually prefer you to set the trace directly these days as that's a more general mechanism. Demonstrating after running the above script:

```
% base_model_lib foo
foo
% foo configure
about to read the -filename
{-filename {} abc.0.8870089169996832}
% foo configure -filename
about to read the -filename
-filename {} abc.0.9588680136757288
% foo cget -filename
about to read the -filename
abc.0.694705847974264
```

As you can see, we're controlling exactly what is read via the standard mechanism (in this case, some randomly varying gibberish, but you can do better than that).